# Mongoose and findAndModify

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use `node.js` with `mongoose` plugin. All I need is to try to select a single document with a query like:

```
{
  _id: '52261c53daa9d6b74e00000c',
  someAdditionalFlag: 156
}
```

and if and only if it succeeds then change that flag to another value. Moreover, find and modify operation needs to be **atomic**. Please, how to achieve that using Mongoose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `findAndModify` for this as you don't need the original document.  So you can just use `update` like this:

```
MyModel.update({
  _id: '52261c53daa9d6b74e00000c',
  someAdditionalFlag: 156
}, {
  $set: {someAdditionalFlag: newValue }
},
function(err, numAffected) { ... });
```

In the callback, `numAffected` will be 1 if a change was made, otherwise 0.

Comment: @Zlatko Yes, just include a `{multi: true}` parameter before the callback parameter.

Comment: Awesome! Both you with helpful answering and the awesome tech we're using :)